# Primitive roots of unity generating groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

So I know that the primitve roots of unity are given by
$$\xi_n = \left[1, \frac{2\pi}{n} \right] = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right).$$

Let $\xi_4=\left[1,\frac{\pi}{2} \right]=i$ be the  primitive fourth root of unity and  $\xi_8=\left[1, \frac{\pi}{4} \right]$ the primitive eighth root of unity.

I need to find the subgroups of $(\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ generated by $\xi_4$ resp $\xi_8$ and the cosets of $C_4$ in $C_8$.

For the elements I had the idea that they would be given by the $n$-th unit roots

$${\xi_n}^{j} = \left[1, \frac{2\pi j}{n} \right], j \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$$

So if I am right then the elements in $C_4$
would be $\{\xi^{0}_{4},\xi^{1}_{4}, \xi^{2}_{4}, \xi^{3}_{4} \}$
and for $C_8=\{\xi^{0}_{8},\xi^{1}_{8}, \xi^{2}_{8}, \xi^{3}_{8}, \xi^{4}_{8}, \xi^{5}_{8}, \xi^{6}_{8}, \xi^{7}_{8} \}$ (still not 100% sure about this).

However writing down the elements makes it clear that $C_4 \subseteq C_8$.
What I still struggle with are the cosets, are the left and right cosets equal here? and how can I determine them?

Comment: The notation is usually $\zeta_n$ for a primitive $n$-th root of unity. For the same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365382/primitive-roots-of-unity-subgroups) (deleted now). Try to visualize the eigths roots of unity on the circle in the complex plane. The pwoers of $\zeta_8$ are just the other eights roots of unity.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you, I had the idea that I needed to visualize it on a circle, but what  I don’t quite understand is that, how do I get the elements inside the subgroups? The elements would just be the edges of the polygon?

Comment: I meant the nth roots of unity would be the edges; but how could I specify the elements inside?

Comment: The subgroup generated by $\zeta_4$ would be $\{1,\zeta_4,\zeta_4^2,\zeta_4^3\}$, because $\zeta_4^4=1$. In the same way you can see the other subgroups.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: thank you, so the elements inside the groups would be the powers {0,...,4-1} resp. {0,...,8-1} of the primitive roots?and thus, $C_4 \subseteq C_8$? Could you also help me in how I could find the cosets of $C_4 \subseteq C_8$?

Comment: You should clarify your Question by editing the body and not merely by adding Comments.  Readers who are willing to help should not be required to guess how the information given in Comments relates to the text in the body of the Question.

Comment: @hardmath: everything I have written in the comments is also written in the text?! I do not get your point? there is no new information from my side in the comments!

Comment: Visualizing these numbers as points on a circle is a good idea.  We refer to these as "cyclic groups" because they are generated (multiplicatively) by a single element.  At the appropriate step the powers of that element "wrap around" to the multiplicative identity.  Thanks for updating your Question.

Comment: @hardmath: Thank you, I can also update the post later with a visualization. The visualization or simply calculating all the elements would show that $C_4$ is a subset,  what I still do not know is how to determine the cosets

Comment: You are perhaps overthinking it.  You found some examples, that $C_4$ is a subgroup of $C_8$.  Perhaps doing the group $C_6$ will more forcefully suggest what the pattern is?

Comment: What is that bracket notation, $[a,b]$?

Comment: @hardmath: thanks, I will try it and see if it can help me

Comment: @mr_e_man: the bracket $[a,b]$ here stands for  $a*cos(b)+i r* sin(b)$